# Why do these two pieces of code using constexpr, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ and char * have different results?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, constexpr

I have this code where if you comment out the line commented "*But this doesn't work?!*" it compiles just fine, but if you don't, the compiler generates an error.

At least, [gcc 8.2 generates an error](https://godbolt.org/z/dyHGME).

But, they seem identical to me. What's the problem? Is this legal code at all?

```
template <int x>
struct test_template {
    static int size() { return x; }
};

constexpr int ce_strlen(char const *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i]) ++i;
    return i;
}

int joe()
{
    constexpr int plen = ce_strlen(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__); // This works
    test_template<plen> a; // This declaration is valid.
    test_template<ce_strlen(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)> b; // But this doesn't work?!
    return a.size() + b.size();
}
```

I ran into this while trying to come up with [a way to create profile tags for an intrusive profiling system at compile time](https://godbolt.org/z/ooLbAQ). I succeeded, but my final code does not involve using `ce_strlen`.

Comment: Well, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` isn't standard. (`__func__` is, but may not be unique enough for your purposes, especially in the presence of overloads and templates.)

Comment: @aschepler - I believe there's been a movement to standardize something like `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. But, that's why I put in the gcc tag. :-) That and clang doesn't seem to have a problem with the code. Also, lambdas. Lambdas are a really interesting case here.

Comment: Given that `ce_strlen` returns an `int`, which is also the same type as `test_template`'s non-type template parameter - there's no reason these should have different behavior. I struggle with [expr.const], but at least I'm pretty sure these should either both compile or both fail.

Comment: Filed [87399](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87399). My best guess is that _both_ should fail, but it's surely a bug that both behave differently.

Comment: According to [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html), `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is constexpr, so both cases *should* compile.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed this is a bug in GCC as discussed in the comments, but I thought I'd throw in some additional insight as to the nature of this bug. In the GCC [NEWS file](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/gcc/cp/NEWS#L337) there is this line:

> - `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` are now treated as variables by the parser; previously they were treated as string constants.  So code like `printf (__FUNCTION__ ": foo")` must be rewritten to `printf ("%s: foo", __FUNCTION__)`. This is necessary for templates.

But `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` isn't really a variable, it's a special case treated in the parser as we see in `constexpr.c`:

```
    case DECL_EXPR:
      {
    tree decl = DECL_EXPR_DECL (body);
    if (TREE_CODE (decl) == USING_DECL
        /* Accept __func__, __FUNCTION__, and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__.  */
        || DECL_ARTIFICIAL (decl))
      return NULL_TREE;
    return error_mark_node;
}
```

If it really was a variable, we'd expect it to pass the same test cases as these:

```
constexpr const char* s2 = "TEST";
constexpr const char* s3 = s2;
test_template<ce_strlen("TEST")> c;
test_template<ce_strlen(s2)> d;
test_template<ce_strlen(s3)> e;
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting detail on what's going on inside gcc to cause this problem. :-)